# How to hide Or disable specific page from menus inside Appearance in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide or disable specific page from menus list from admin appearance.How can I do this?

[Screenshot of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBtMe.png)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks for your attention.
I want to do this so that we can not add this to our menus or as well as not want to show in frontend anywhere.